# Upperbound for sets

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

From Spivak's calculus, this is how he proves the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Set $A$

$A = \{x: a \le x \le b\}$ and $f$ is negative on the interval $[a, x]$ He says:

Since $a$ is in $A$: in fact there is some $\delta > 0$ such that $A$ contains all points $x$ satisfying $a \le x < a + \delta$ Since $f$ is continous on [a, b] and $f(a) < 0$ **similarly $b$ is an upperbound for $A$.** in fact there is some $\delta$ such that **all points $x$ satisfying $b - \delta < x \le b$ are upperbounds for $A$.** this follows sine $f(b)>0$

Carefully read the **bolded** parts.

It is impossible to have $\ge2$ upperbounds, this was proven before, then how can we have this?

if $b$ is already an upperbound then how can some $c$ --> $c < b$ be an upperbound for the set, that doesnt make sense.

Comment: *least upper bound* (if exists) is unique. not upper bounds. a set can have several upper bounds. consider $[0,1] \subset \mathbb{R}.$ then every element $\geq 1$ is an upper bound the set. but $1$ is **the** least upper bound.

Comment: Yes, I see now. $\sup S = 1$ but because 1/2 < 1 it is a least upperbound

Comment: it's least upper bound because for every other upper bound $u,$ we have $1 \leq u.$ Or you can argue (in this particular case) that $1$ is an upper bound which is also an element of the given set. it's not a least upper bound *only* because $1/2 < 1.$